# Proper way to update pandas dataframe with values from another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

What is the proper way to update multiple columns in one dataframe with values from another dataframe?

Say I have these two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['4', 'val1', 'val2.4', 'val3.4'],
                    ['5', 'val1', 'val2.5', 'val3.5'],
                    ['6', 'val1', 'val2.6', 'val3.6'],
                    ['7', 'val1', 'val2.7', 'val3.7']],
                   columns=['account_id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['6', 'VAL2.6', 'VAL3.6'],
                    ['5', 'VAL2.5', 'VAL3.5']],
                   columns=['account_id', 'field2', 'field3'])
```

Of note, df2 has only a subset of d1's rows (in some random order) and columns.

I'd like to replace values in df1 with values from df2 (where they exist, joining on account_id, ala an SQL UPDATE).

One solution is something like

```
cols_to_update = ['field2', 'field3']
df1.loc[df1.account_id.isin(df2.account_id), cols_to_update] = df2[cols_to_update].values
```

But that doesn't handle the join and results in

```
    account_id    field1    field2    field3
0   4             val1      val2.4    val3.4
1   5             val1      VAL2.6    VAL3.6
2   6             val1      VAL2.5    VAL3.5
3   7             val1      val2.7    val3.7
```

where account_id 6 now has the wrong values.

My questions are:

1. How do I use indexes to make something like that work?
2. Is there a merge() or join() solution that isn't so tedious with combining duplicate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the values of `df2` before assigning i.e

```
cols_to_update = ['field2', 'field3']

df1.loc[df1.account_id.isin(df2.account_id), cols_to_update] = df2.sort_values(['account_id'])[cols_to_update].values

   account_id field1  field2  field3
0          4   val1  val2.4  val3.4
1          5   val1  VAL2.5  VAL3.5
2          6   val1  VAL2.6  VAL3.6
3          7   val1  val2.7  val3.7
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with sorting both dataframes to make sure the key order was as I was assuming.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the function [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) of panda's dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],'B': [400, 500, 600]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df)
df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```